# PHP Contact Form not working with Outlook email addresses

Tags: php, forms, outlook

I have a contact form on a html page. The form data is sent to a PHP page which sends the info to an email address. It works for addresses *@gmail, *@hotmail.com but the person who needs to receive it has Outlook set-up for their website.com address and it doesn't work. Is there another setting I need somewhere?

Here is PHP code:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "myname@website.com";
$EmailTo = "receiver@website.com";
$Subject = "Website Contact Form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$Location = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['location'])); 
$Phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Comments = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['comments'])); 



// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Location: ";
$Body .= $Location;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $Phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Comments: ";
$Body .= $Comments;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";

?>
```

Comment: What do "it doesn't work" means?

Comment: Outlook emails don't receive email

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up quite a bit.

There is a strong possibility that the mail client (in this case outlook) is configured to filter messages that lack proper headers.  This could be at the client point or at the server connection at smtp time.  The main thrust of the issue is that the basic php `mail()` core function is almost universally mistrusted due to its potential for abuse by spammers.

You should try using a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to help guide you to setting the reply-to and other headers properly.

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look into this